# Unable to integrate Application Insights SDK with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, azure-application-insights

I followed [the instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-android/) step by step. A popup shows "Application Insights SDK integrated", however it is actually not, at least not successfully. Some libraries apparently have not been added because com.microsoft.applicationinsights.library.ApplicationInsights cannot be imported. Some related contents have not been added to AndroidManifest.xml.
Android Studio shows an IDE fatal error with the following details:

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.intellij.integration.IntegrateSDKTask.getDependenciesBlock(IntegrateSDKTask.java:219)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.intellij.integration.IntegrateSDKTask.integrateDependency(IntegrateSDKTask.java:159)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.intellij.integration.IntegrateSDKTask.integrateWithBuildFile(IntegrateSDKTask.java:106)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.intellij.integration.IntegrateSDKTask.integrateWithModule(IntegrateSDKTask.java:85)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.intellij.integration.IntegrateSDKTask.access$300(IntegrateSDKTask.java:42)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.intellij.integration.IntegrateSDKTask$1.run(IntegrateSDKTask.java:67)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:161)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:332)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:569)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:818)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:197)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:633)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:363)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:76)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.run(CoreProgressManager.java:293)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Task.queue(Task.java:74)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.intellij.actions.IntegrateSDKAction.doIntegration(IntegrateSDKAction.java:188)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.intellij.actions.IntegrateSDKAction.access$600(IntegrateSDKAction.java:32)
    at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.intellij.actions.IntegrateSDKAction$3.run(IntegrateSDKAction.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:332)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:569)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Could anyone offer a tip on how to remedy this?

Comment: It looks like the NPE occurs when trying to parse your `build.gradle` file to add the necessary dependencies.

1. Does your module's build.gradle file have a `dependencies {...}` closure?
2. Which version of Android SDK and Build Tools are you using in your project?

Comment: Thank you, Matthias, for lending a hand. Yes, the build.gradle has a dependencies block. compileSdkVersion is 23, and buildToolsVersion is "23.0.1"

Comment: Hi Hong. This seems to be a bug in the build integration step. Unfortunately we don't have details or ETA on a fix as of now.

Comment: Thank you for the update, Matthias.  I am wondering if one can manually do what the integration does (e.g. adding relevant contents to the manifest time, copying necessary files to the appropriate folder).  If so, could you point to document explaining exactly what the integration does?

Comment: Hi Hong, sure, the plugin basically automates the tasks from the original setup documentation (https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Android#3) for the Android SDK.

Comment: Great!  Thanks a lot.  That is all I need. I do this once in a great while, so doing it manually is not a big deal.  Could you combine your comments into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @MatthiasWenz Could you tell me where com.microsoft.applicationinsights.library.ApplicationInsights package (jar file?) resides?  Android Studio cannot resolve import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.library.ApplicationInsights;

Comment: The Application Insights SDK for Android is hosted on Maven Central: See http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.microsoft.azure%7Capplicationinsights-android%7C1.0-beta.9%7Caar for the latest version. Please note that we are phasing out Application Insights, as HockeyApp is now our main offering in the mobile space.

Comment: @MatthiasWenz  Thanks a lot for the update.  Very sorry to see Application Insights, a fantastic tool, is being phased out. We will keep using AI as long as it works.

Comment: We are working hard on HockeyApp to make it a compelling replacement for Application Insights and have just announced many of the same new features in our Preseason program: http://hockeyapp.net/preseason/